# Concatenate Ajax serialized data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, serialization

I have a form with a input field where users introduces data. I use Ajax to send it and I want for every field to send to `concat.` a value. So if the user introduce test. The visible result should
be `www.google.com/test`.
This is my code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="test" name="test">
</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#formid").length) {
        $("#formid").submit(function(event) {
            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: form.serialize(),
                //success...
```

And when I doo `...data: form.serialize() + '&test=' + testtest,` it will just add another value to the `id test`.
How can I do the concat?

Comment: Can you give an example to clarify which parts you want to concatenate?

Comment: Hey @qrsngky I want to concatenate user input  from the form with a string. For example user input: 123, 321, prefixed string: http://, final result http:// 123, http:// 321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure your users have modern browsers, you can use FormData API to modify the contents, then use URLSearchParams API to serialize it, for example:

```
let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('formid'));
for (let key of formData.keys()) {
   formData.set(key, 'http://' + formData.get(key))
}

var url = form.attr('action');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url, 
    data: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString()
});
```

Edit: an example to match a list of keys but not all keys:

```
let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('formid'));
let specialKeys = ['specialKey1', 'specialKey2'];
for (let key of formData.keys()) {
   if(specialKeys.includes(key)) formData.set(key, 'http://' + formData.get(key))
}

var url = form.attr('action');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url, 
    data: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString()
});
```

Edit: To handle the case of duplicate keys in forms, we can't unambiguously use `.get` and `.set` methods, instead we should append the data to a new form data, for example:

```
let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('formid'));
let specialKeys = ['specialKey1', 'specialKey2'];
let modifiedFormData = new FormData(); 
for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
    if(specialKeys.includes(key)) {
        modifiedFormData.append( key, 'http://'+ value )
    }else{
        modifiedFormData.append( key, value )
    }
}
let newDataAsString = new URLSearchParams(modifiedFormData).toString();
var url = form.attr('action');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: newDataAsString,
});
```

Comment: @Is working somehow, but where should I define the id I need, because I do not want to be generic, I want this to apply just to one field

Comment: if you just need one special key, you can do something like this:
`if(key === 'specialKey') formData.set(key, 'http://' + formData.get(key))`

If you have more than one special key, you can also keep a list in an array. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I have a question, what if I have 2 input fields with same id( because i have  add field on click function and is extending the parent input field), adding this will only list the 1st input field and second will be ignored?

Comment: Good point. This is the limitation of using formData.get and formData.set when two keys collide. But there is a way to solve this problem. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I tried, is returning nothing, do you know where i am wrong ?
https://jsfiddle.net/hvfd9km6/8/

Comment: form data relies on "name" rather than "id", so you use `<input type="text" name="test" value="1">` and `<input type="text" name="test" value="3">`.
Also note that even though it's ok to have a duplicate "name", the "id" needs to be unique (the 'id' won't be used for form data, but has other purposes).

Comment: Many many THX. Is working as expected. Thank you for the explanation, now every thing make sense so much!